# Transposed Matrix Transformation

Tags: matrices, transpose

Consider a vector y containing the y values of some putative linear relation in the form of $y=ax+b$ and matrices A and B:
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}         
        x_1 & 1\\
        x_2 & 1 \\
        ... & ...\\
        x_i & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

$$B= \left(\begin{matrix}
a\\
b
\end{matrix}\right)$$

In very basic linear regression theory it is stated that when the residuals are $ r=AB-y$, then $ SSQ = r^Tr = (AB-y)^T (AB-y)$, which is logic. However, then we can simplify this to $ y^Ty-2B^TA^Ty+B^TA^TAB$. I don't really understand how we get this two times B transposed A transposed y, I would simply get: $y^Ty-B^TA^Ty+ABy^T+B^TA^TAB$ instead. When I tried to fill in some numbers for the matrices A B en vector y, I indeed find that $ ABy^T $ equals $ A^TB^Ty $. What is the reasoning/theory behind this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a linear regression, you only obtain an estimate of $B$. Let $\widehat{B}$ be this estimate. The vector of residuals is: $r = y - A\widehat{B}$.

Using your notations, if $A$ is an $n \times p$ matrix, $A B$ is an $n \times 1$ matrix. We also have that $y^{T}$ is a $1 \times n$ matrix. This means that $A B y^{T}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. Instead of $+ ABy^{T}$, you should have $- y^{T} A B$, which is a $1 \times 1$ matrix.

You could then write:
$$y^{T} A B = (y^{T} A B)^{T} = B^{T} A^{T} y.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to make sure I understand correctly, because it is a 1x1 matrix, we can state that $ y^TAB=(y^TAB)^T $, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.